# How do I fetch relative to a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I have a file tree:

```
index.html

  | js
  |
  | data.json
  | script.js
```

`index.html` is just `script.js`

`script.js`:

```
(async function() {
  var req = await fetch("data.json");
  var json = await req.json();
  ...
})();
```

I'm trying to access `data.json` from `script.js` (`js` folder) instead of `index.html`.

So I can't just use `js/script.js`

How would I do this?

Comment: If `script.js` is in a subdirectory, `index.html` should contain `<script src="js/script.js">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can get a path to the currently running script (if it's not ESM), using [document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)

Untested, but this would suggest you can build the path like this:

```js
const dataUrl = new URL('data.json', document.currentScript.src);
const req = await fetch(dataUrl);
// etc
```

Answer (score -2):

Even though the `data.json` is in the same folder as `script.js`, since both these files are inside the `js` folder relative to `index.html` you would have to use

```js
  var req = await fetch("js/data.json");
```

Comment: My guess is OP wants the fetch to work _regardless_ of what path included it. This makes an assumption about how the script was included.

Comment: @Evert I made no assumption here. He had included that information in his question.

Comment: fwiw i didn't downvote you, just mentioned this because i had a feeling it was too simple of a solution